# Trying to understand _Underscore library

Tags: underscore.js

Having a hard time getting my head around the [_Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) library, the basics I think I'm picking up, but I think it's the terminology that is giving me problems.

For example I have the following Object:

```
CA3 "BAA"
vol_2007 0.15
vol_2008 0.2
vol_2009 0.25
vol_2010 0.3
vol_2011 0.600

CA3 "LUF"
vol_2007 1.13
vol_2008 0.4
vol_2009 1.6
vol_2010 2.8
vol_2011 0.43
```

I've arrived at this with the following:

```js
var fieldtogroup = 'CA3';

var groups = _.groupBy(tmp,function (name) { return name[fieldtogroup] });
var sums = _.map(groups, function (group) {
    return _.reduce(group, function (a, b) { return b; }, 0);
});
```

The first problem I have is that if I use:

```js
return _.reduce(group, function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
```

I get an Object back of rubbish, I can see that the _Underscore documentation explains perfect that the 'a' is the current value and the 'b' is the new, but this just doesn't work.  Can someone explain why this is?  Do I need a clause within the function to determine if the values are numeric before doing the calculation?

Also, ultimately, I want to be able to return an array of objects similar to:

```
vol_2007: 0.15,1.13
vol_2008: 0.2,0.4
vol_2009: 0.25, 1.6
vol_2010: 0.3, 2.8
vol_2011: 0.600,0.43
```

I've managed to do this by 'kinda' rotating the Object, going through the array several times and pushing values into another array but I'm positive _Underscore would be able to do this for me yet I can't understand how.

If someone can enlighten me on these I'd really appreciate it, I've grasped the basics of the library but this has me stumped!

- edit *

Worked out the last problem with the [`_.pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) command which is wonderful, but still getting errors when using the Reduce.

[image]

The 'more' simply contains values for vol_2009 -> vol_2011

Comment: You you please format your Object as JSON? This would clarify the actual structure. You can use `JSON.stringify(tmp)` for that

Comment: @Bergi - sorry didn't understand, are you asking me to supply a copy of the JSON string, or if I can do this in code?  If the latter, it's already a JSON string.

Comment: Yes, if you have that object as a literal in your code already you also can post that. I need the structure of your object, which I can't read from the CSV you supplied us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the sum-reduction on the wrong objects. See what your `groups = _.groupBy(tmp, 'CA3')` returns:

```
{ // arrays of objects grouped by their CA3 property:
    BAA: [
        {
            CA3: "BAA",
            vol_2007: 0.15
            …
        },
        …
    ],
    Rum: [
        {
            CA3: "Rum",
            …
        }, {
            CA3: "Rum",
            …
        },
        …
    ],
    …
}
```

You can't sum those objects.

Instead, you seem to want to group the property values of the objects in those arrays again by their property names:

```
byCAandVol = _.map(groups, function(arr) {
    var res = {};
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        for (var prop in arr[i])
            if (prop != "CA3")
                if (prop in res)
                    res[prop].pus(arr[i][prop]);
                else
                    res[prop] = [arr[i][prop]];
    return res;
});
```

This is a bit like a group-by-each-property. Now you've got

```
{ // arrays of objects grouped by their CA3 property:
    BAA: {
        vol_2007: [0.15, …],
        vol_2008: […]
        …
    },
    Rum: {
        vol_2007: …
    },
    …
}
```

Now you can sum those arrays with your reduce function, wrapped in two mappings:

```
sumsByCAandVol = _.map(byCAandVol, function (group) {
    return _.map(group, function(vols) {
        return _.reduce(vols, function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
    });
});
```

Or, you don't do that in an extra step and build sums instead of arrays right in the group-by-each-property function.

Comment: wow!!! That's a lot to digest.  Can 100% understand about the wrong grouping, still thinking of it as a SQL statement which I guess is incorrect.  It's perfectly explain Bergi, so my thanks, will digest it all.